# React js call function from another function with parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react js, I was calling the grpc from the client end. I am receiving the blockchain in from another function  and passing it to `GetBlockInfo` but once received parameter value I am unable to pass inside the `getblock` function. I need help to know how the parameter is passed using the user effect inside the child function.

```
function GetBlockInfo(block_height) {
  //I am receiving the block height from different function 

  const [blockresponse, setPost] = useState([]);

  const getblock = (value) => {
    //cannot find the value here 
    var block_Req = new BlockRequest();
    block_Req.setHeight(value);

    client.getBlock(block_Req, null, function (err, response) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("the block details", err);
      } else {
        let result = response.toObject();
        setPost(result);
      }
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
const interval = setInterval(() => getblock(block_height), 8000);
return () => {
  clearInterval(interval);
};
}, [blockResponse]);
  
  return <div><div>;
}
```

Comment: I think you need to extract block_height. Try `function GetBlockInfo({ block_height })`

Comment: its not working thanks for replay

Comment: btw. you should get rid of return statement in the `useEffect`

Comment: your `useEffect` should raise a warning because `block_height` is not on useEffect's array of deps.

Comment: I have updated the code, still not able to find solution.